# Factorise WPF datatemplate trigger is possible?

Tags: wpf, xaml, refactoring

Hello I have this XAML code

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="BLUnitPriceTemplate">
        <TextBlock x:Name="CellTB"
            Padding="10,3"
            Style="{StaticResource DarkSmallFontStyle}"
            Text="{Binding UnitPrice, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}" />
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LineType}" Value="Total">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PinkBackgroundBrush}"
                    TargetName="CellTB" />
                <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource SmallFontStyle}"
                    TargetName="CellTB" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LineType}" Value="Rate">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCCCCC"
                     TargetName="CellTB" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="BLRemiseTemplate">
        <TextBlock x:Name="CellTB"
           Padding="10,3"
           Style="{StaticResource DarkSmallFontStyle}"
           Text="{Binding Remise, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}" />
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LineType}" Value="Total">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PinkBackgroundBrush}"
                    TargetName="CellTB" />
                <Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource SmallFontStyle}"
                    TargetName="CellTB" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LineType}" Value="Rate">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCCCCC"
                    TargetName="CellTB" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
```

But as you can see the data template trigger is almost the same. Only the Text Binding change.

I find it redondant and ugly AF

is there a way to factorize the data template trigger to use the same in multiple DataTemplate?

Edit:
Has the answer was a good try but didn't seem to work because of the Style Setter inside Style definition. I chose to Add some context while I work around it if someone read this and want to give it a try.

My templates are used by this DataGrid

```
 <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Details}">
            <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn
              CellStyle="{StaticResource AppManagementAddCellStyle}"
              Header="{x:Static languages:ResAbbreviations.PU}"
              Width="60"
              CellTemplate="{StaticResource BLUnitPriceTemplate}"
                            />
                <DataGridTemplateColumn
              CellStyle="{StaticResource AppManagementAddCellStyle}"
              Header="{x:Static languages:ResAbbreviations.DiscountPercent}"
              Width="60"
              CellTemplate="{StaticResource BLRemiseTemplate}"
                            />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Comment: Move the Triggers to the TextBlock Style.

Comment: Wouldn't the binding of lineType be inaccessible in the TextBlock  context? as I bind the TextBlock text?

Comment: The DataContext should be inherited, so no.

Comment: ok will try this then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the Triggers to the TextBlock Style:

```
<Style x:Key="CellTBStyle" TargetType="TextBlock" 
       BasedOn="{StaticResource DarkSmallFontStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10,3"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LineType}" Value="Total">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PinkBackgroundBrush}"/>
            <!-- more Setters -->
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding LineType}" Value="Rate">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCCCCC"/>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
<DataTemplate x:Key="BLUnitPriceTemplate">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CellTBStyle}"
               Text="{Binding UnitPrice, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}" />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="BLRemiseTemplate">
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CellTBStyle}"
               Text="{Binding Remise, StringFormat={}{0:N2}}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: I got a problem with this code i'm currently searching around but it's say.
"the oject Style is not authorize to affect the Style property" 

I think its because the Background and Style was the one on DataTemplate and not TextBlock one

Comment: Oh, that is because of `<Setter Property="Style" Value="{StaticResource SmallFontStyle}"/>`  inside a Style, which will of course not work. You should solve that by adding the Setters from that Style directly. At `more Setters`, see the edit.

Comment: that was i was trying and it work fine. 
The only différence between two style was |<Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="White" />|
So i past this in the more setters Comment

Comment: I'm gonna mark your answer as good but juste before. 
The text padding is not the same on all colomn (i have more than two ^^)
Is it possible to move the padding out of the Style for textBlock?

Comment: Sure, just set it directly on the TextBlock, as you did before. You may still keep a default value in the Style.

Comment: O right im dumb i was thinking it was set in Style and not directly thank a lot :)